# CSS Flexbox align 1 item horizontally and 2 vertically

Tags: css, flexbox

I have the following HTML:

```
 <div class="icon-box">
    <div class="icon">
      <svg>...</svg>
    </div>
    <h3>Title here</h3>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor...</p>
 </div>
```

My CSS:

```
.icon-box {
  display: flex;
}
```

The result:

[image]

How can i get the following using flexbox without changing the HTML:

[image]

I am trying to align the icon to left and the heading and paragraph to its right on the same column. Without changing/adding new HTML.

Comment: All you need is the SVG, H3 and P elements, the rest you can do with CSS. Unless you specifically need to use flexbox, in which case I don't think you'll be able to accomplish this without a wrapper around the two text elements.

Comment: Use CSS Grid layout. Simple solution. No changes to the HTML.

Comment: wrapping your `h3` and `p` in a `div` solves your problem quickly, but why u don't want to change the html,

Answer (score 1):

Try using `flex-direction: column;` on main parent and regular `display: flex;` (`flex-direction: row;`) on the child of parent.

```css
.icon-box {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.icon {
  display: flex;
  gap: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="icon-box">
    <div class="icon">
      <img src="https://dummyimage.com/50/000000/f2009d&text=SVG">
      <h3>Title here</h3>
    </div>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor...</p>
 </div>
```

Comment: I did not give downvotes, but in your answer, '.icon' , 'h3' , 'p' are placed on a column! while in the question, CyberJ requested another thing.

Comment: @ArmanEbrahimiWh ere did he request "another thing"? He wanted to change his result to the desired screenshot with only using flex box, and that's exactly what I did.

Comment: @CyberJ see the adjusted.

Comment: First, your 'h3' tag was out of div(.icon). But now fixed. I hope @Cyber accept your answer :)

Comment: @ArmanEbrahimi me too! Hopefully this is the one!